# Calibrating AR-Drone after flight

Tags: calibration, ros-kinetic, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am using ROS to fly a real AR-Drone. My problem is that after a takeoff-flight-land sequence if I try to takeoff again the drone can't stabilize properly and will not fly well.

If I take out the battery and put it back in the drone preforms its calibration (with the routers spinning) and then I can takeoff and fly again with no issues. My question is how do I make the drone preform that calibration without taking the battery out and in again?

It is very annoying to take the battery out and in every time, and also I don't know if this is going to cause problems for the drone/batteries in the future.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288866/calibrating-ar-drone-after-flight/) by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You didn't mention which version you're using in your question so I'm assuming that you're using the 2.0. While your drone is on a flat surface, run

```
rosservice call /ardrone/flattrim
```

From the [docs](https://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services.html#flat-trim)

> ### Flat Trim

Calling `ardrone/flattrim` service without any parameter will send a “Flat Trim” request to AR-Drone to re-calibrate its rotation estimates assuming that it is on a flat surface. Do not call this service while Drone is flying or while the drone is not actually on a flat surface.

If this still doesn't work, then try the calibration command from the phone app (again, while on a flat surface).

---

**Edit:**

If the lights are red then you probably have an error due a high acceleration (even carrying the drone can cause this) or rotating the drone too much. Publish an `std_msgs/Empty` message to the `ardrone/reset` topic to reset it and then flat trim.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-04-17**:
thank you very much! I didn't mention which version of ardrone because this happened to me both with 1.0 and 2.0. Still I should have probably mentioned it, sorry. I am currently also having other drone problems, so I can't test it with flying, when I will I will approve the answer as correct.

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-04-27**:
Sorry for the delay. I finally got my drone back on track. using `rosservice call /ardrone/flattrim` I get a message saying "flat trim set" but it doesnt seem to do anything. The lights on my ardrone2 are still red and the propellers didn't move in order to recalibrate.

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-04-27**:
Also I cant use the phone app, as I am connecting to my drone through an internal LAN I have setup and made the drone connect to. Thus my drones router is no longer visible. Do you have any other ideas by any chance? Or maybe I need to do something together with the flat trim? Thanks again for help!

**Comment by [oha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31727/oha/) on 2018-04-29**:
Thank you so much! it seems to work, I think, I have some weird behavior still but I think that has to do with my actual drone and the reset and reconfiguration work. Small correction, I first needed to flattrim and then reset (not the other way around like you mention). Thanks again!